# Text to speech syllables audio segments connection rules

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I'm looking for some research about creating text-to-speech program from zero without using of any exist TTS tool, libraries etc. Mainly about rules of creating and combining audio segments.

I want use it for few  rare ancient languages with a very simplifying circumstance in the language itself. First, it is not to large range of verbal base about 1000 words and second  it is pronounced as it is written, so pronunciation is absolutely equal to each letter in word, for example word:

```
parjashif
```

which means both "father of" and "son of father" syllables is:

```
par  
ja
shif
```

and all exist variants for other words with same parts is:

```
par
ja

1.shif
2.kif
3.hof
4.hefi
```

thats all, as you can see there is only 4 variants

So, only thing which must be taking into the account, it is connection intervals  between exist syllables, to make pronunciation does not sound discrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the trick of properly implemented text-to-speech software. The pronunciation depends on context, if you do not care about context, the sound will be discrete and unnatural. The proper system records all syllables in context and when select them for concatenation it pays a lot of attention to smooth transition between elements.

An option for you would be to split your original database on diphones and try to concatenated diphones instead of syllables. It will be much more smooth.

Overall, even if you start from scratch, it is better to read the theory first. At least something like [Building Synthetic Voices](http://festvox.org/bsv/) or a "Speech Synthesis" textbook by Paul Taylor.

Comment: Hello,  of course, the theory is exactly what I'm looking for, and it seems sufficient for me  to start, so thank you for your answer